# Python 3.6 cx_freeze ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, cx-freeze

I froze a python 3.6 program with cx_freeze, and it worked just fine. But as soon as I tried to run it, I got this error message.

[image]

Does anyone know what to do? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

try using
import tkinter
(small 't' instead  of capital)

Comment: I tried that. it was in the ImageTk.py file and did not work when I changed it

Comment: Then I think tkinter module is not installed.Please check and try installing it   if it's not installed using this code in cmd      'python -m pip install tkinter'

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the dir names in the 'lib' folder (in my case it was 'build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\lib'). I had a similar issue (without the 'ImportError: DLL load failed...') and found that the 'lib' directory contained a "Tkinter" folder. Changing its name to lowercase 'tkinter' did the trick and made the .exe run just fine.

Comment: This answer was the solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error more clearly, it stated in a comment that if importing _tkinter failed, your computer isn't configured to use tkinter. You should download tk and ttk to make it work.

And According to http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter :

> If it fails with "No module named _tkinter" or "Tkinter", your Python configuration
>   needs to be modified to include this module (which is an extension
>   module implemented in C). Do not edit Modules/Setup (it is out of
>   date). You may have to install Tcl and Tk (when using RPM, install the
>   -devel RPMs as well) and/or edit the setup.py script to point to the right locations where Tcl/Tk is installed. If you install Tcl/Tk in
>   the default locations, simply rerunning "make" should build the
>   _tkinter extension.

Comment: when I ran it in the shell and ran it as a .py file, it worked perfectly. would I have to install it for that to happen, or is it just for freezing?

Comment: You can also try including tkinter in the setup.py file